# c++ long to char array (8 byte) to long

Tags: c++

How can i change a `long` into a `char` array with 8 Byte and
how can i change a `char` array with 8 Byte into `long` ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    long num=33;
    char* z;
    z = new char[8];
    z =  reinterpret_cast<char *>(&num); // long to char array
    long r;
    r = reinterpret_cast<long>(&z); // char array to long
    cout << r << "\n";  // why is the output not 33
    printf("%x ", z[0]); //print the 8 Byte char array
    printf("%x ", z[1]);
    printf("%x ", z[2]);
    printf("%x ", z[3]);
    printf("%x ", z[4]);
    printf("%x ", z[5]);
    printf("%x ", z[6]);
    printf("%x ", z[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output `r` not 33?

Comment: The second `reinterpret_cast` call is promised a `<long>` but is given a `<long *>`

Comment: Your logic also makes the unwise presumption that a `long` is eight bytes. Use `sizeof`

Comment: s h, `long` is at least 32-bits.  Consider `long long` for at least 64.

Comment: The first `reinterpret_cast` is creating a memory leak, since the pointer to the `new char[]` memory is being lost.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Using `long long` you go the other direction (could have more than 64 bits); s h seems to intend to use a signed integral type of exactly 8 bytes, to `int64_t` would be the best choice. (IF `long long` is used, there should at least be `static_assert(sizeof(long long) == 8, "oh no, why didn't I use a fixed width integer type");`)

Comment: @fabian Further: Using _unsigned_ types like `uint64_t`, for this task avoids the usual sign problems.  Highly portable code would compare with `ULLONG_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu` as that accounts for `CHAR_BITS > 8` and padding.

Answer (score 8):

Post-C++20: Use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast)

Pre-C++20: Use `std::memcpy`

```
long to_long(char const (&arr)[sizeof(long)])
{
   long res;
   memcpy(&res, arr, sizeof(res));
   return res;
}
```

Comment: In case a reader isn't aware, bit casting won't be useful for serialisation across different systems such as in network communication of file formats due to differences in binary representation.

Comment: Why get memcpy involved, if you can just reinterpret_cast and dereference? `long res = *reinterpret_cast<long*>(arr);`?

Comment: @fabian because that would violate strict-aliasing.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica if you round trip it long -> char[8] -> long, you would get the 33. I assume that's what OP wants (from the title).  No need to get `reinterpret_cast` (and the associated UB) involved.